# Facebook Audience network review iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-audience-network

I just create an App with "Facebook Audience Integration", Everything works fine, I have create my placement ID and I can see "test ads" and "real ads" (if I remove my test device).

But there is a problem, my app is still not in "review" I have this message on the header "Ads Only Visible to Admins and Developers [...]Once your app or site serves 5 ads, we'll check that it complies with our policies.."

[Current state of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7xQJ.png)

My app is live on the store since more than 10 days and my app is stil not in review, but I have more than 5 request on my app

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcwDS.png)

Maybe I missed something?a button to press or just tell me you are in the same situation (maybe).

Do you have an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer by the facebook team support :

> Our review process has some big problems, and we're changing it this week. In the future, your apps should be automatically reviewed within 24 hours, as soon as they start sending any requests to our network. It should be very fast.

Comment: I'm in the same situation with app seemingly in limbo. Any word since then?

Comment: It's fixed by the facebook team.

Comment: how do you contact facebook team support?